# Template inheritance for serving static file on GAE not working

Tags: html, google-app-engine, python-2.7, jinja2

I have a small GAE app that's working fine. I use it to serve a few static files as well like (About page, Privacy and contact page). I put the "about.html" in a /static folder along with the /css, /img and /js. In "app.yaml" I declared the handler:

```
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
```

It all works fine. Now I've abstracted the common contents (navigations, etc) into "_base.html" like this:

```
<html>
<head><title> Page title here</title>
<!--Some header files here -->
</head>

<div id="content">
  {% block bodycontent %}

  {% endblock bodycontent %}    
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

The child file looks like this:

```
{% extends "_base.html" %}
{% block title %} About {% endblock %}
{% block bodycontent %} 

<p>Some contents here...</p>

{% endblock bodycontent %}
```

Now, problem when it displays, the "_base.html" does not render. In fact the whole jinja code just displays. But when I wrote an handler for "about.html" it renders the base html correctly.

Question is, why do I have to create instances b4 I can display static files like About, Privacy pages just because I want to use template inheritance? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You have to render the child. This will render the child and the base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Templates are not static files, by definition. If you want a completely static HTML file, you can of course have one without any handler code. But templates require rendering, which means they need a handler to do it.

Comment: So I have two options: 1.) Make the file completely static without any template or 2:) Provide an handler for the template.
Thanks for the explanation.